# Bot framework detect when user is idling

Tags: c#, botframework

Currently I need my bot to automatically send a message after the user has been idling for 5 minutes. How is this can be achieved.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried first? (in code if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a proactive message to your user based on a timer in your code.

> Proactive messages can be useful in a variety of scenarios. If a bot sets a timer or reminder, it will need to notify the user when the time arrives. Or, if a bot receives a notification from an external system, it may need to communicate that information to the user immediately. For example, if the user has previously asked the bot to monitor the price of a product, the bot will alert the user if it receives notification that the price of the product has dropped by 20%. Or, if a bot requires some time to compile a response to the user's question, it may inform the user of the delay and allow the conversation to continue in the meantime. When the bot finishes compiling the response to the question, it will share that information with the user.

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages

Code example:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages